# Как добавить опрос в телеграмм боте?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Я написал код, в котором опрос отправляется всем пользователям, но после нажатия на один из ответов опрос **не обновляется** для всех пользователей. То есть не видно, что другой участник нажал. Как сделать так, чтобы опрос обновлялся у всех пользователей?

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['poll'])
def poll(message):
    con = sqlite3.connect('users.db')
    with con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute("SELECT id FROM data_base")
        while True:
            row = cur.fetchone()
            if row is None:
                break
            bot.send_poll(row[0], 'Question', options=['1', '2', '3'])
```

Comment: приведите пример кода с которым у вас трудности

Comment: добавил код и написал развернутый вопрос.